# Prove inequalities - mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus

> Prove the following inequalities. If for some numbers $m, M$
>
> $m ≥ f'(x) ≥ M$, $∀ x ∈ (a, b)$, then
>
> $m(b – a) ≤ f(b) – f(a) ≤ M(b – a)$

This should be related to the MVT, just can't seem to find any help for where this proof comes from. TIA!

Comment: By MVT there exists $\theta\in(a,b)$ such that$$m\le f'(\theta)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\le M$$assuming you meant that$$m\le f'(\theta)\le M\qquad\forall\theta\in(a,b)$$

Comment: @Peter Foreman, ah right and then I can multiply the b-a on each side, but why the absolute value?

Comment: Where is the absolute value?

Comment: Apologies I was thinking about a different question with an absolute value. Thanks for the help